# Undefined variable: posts (View: /app/resources/views/bbs/index.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to laravel, I was not able to find solution this error with any searches.
after deploy to Heroku it was show up this error.

this is views/bbs/index.blade.php

```
    <tbody id="tbl">
    @foreach ($posts as $post)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ optional ($post)->id }}</td>
            <td>{{ optional ($post->category)->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ optional ($post->created_at)->format('Y.m.d') }}</td>
            <td>{{ optional ($post)->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ optional ($post)->subject }}</td>
            <td>{!! nl2br(e(Str::limit($post->message, 100))) !!}
            @if ($post->comments->count() >= 1)
                <p><span class="badge badge-primary">コメント：{{ optional ($post->comments)->count() }}件</span></p>
            @endif
            </td>
            <td class="text-nowrap">
                <p><a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">詳細</a></p>
                <p><a href="" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">編集</a></p>
                <p><a href="" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">削除</a></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
```

this is PostsController.php

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;
class PostsController extends Controller{
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();
    return view('bbs.index', ['posts' => $posts]);
}}
```

this is route

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('bbs.index');});
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('bbs', 'PostsController@index')
```

please help in this queries.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use compact() function .

$posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();

return view('bbs.index', compact('posts'));

Comment: thank you! i deleted and add this code. it works.

Comment: This will result in exactly the same data being sent to the view. `compact('posts') === ['posts' => $posts]`

Comment: its good,please mark as a answer.